# ::-moz-selection & jcarousel - trying to fix double click seelction

Tags: css, jcarousel

I have a jcarousel and double clicking next button results in the images being highlighted in blue, on Chrome only.

```
::selection { background: white;}
::-moz-selection {background: white;}
```

This fixes it but means one cannot select (or rather see you are selecting) text on any other parts of the site.

My jcarousel is within:

```
<ul id='product-id-232-carousel' class='product-carousel jcarousel-skin-tango'>
```

So I tried several variations of :

```
ul.product-carousel::selection { background: white;}
ul.product-carousel::-moz-selection {background: white;}
```

To try to restrict the white selection b/g to just the jcarousel but none work.

Thanks,
Kevin

Found a solution:

Wrapped carousel in a div and applied this style:

```
.carouselnoselect{
    -webkit-user-select: none;  
    -moz-user-select: none;     
    -ms-user-select: none;     
    user-select: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `::selection` and everything to do with your carousel plugin not preventing the default action of events properly.

Somewhere in `jcarousel` you should find a click handler for scrolling to next or previous items. It should have `e.preventDefault()` or similar in there, but from what you're saying I would guess it doesn't.

Comment: Hi, you are correct, it does not have that. But I'm not really sure where to put it, if you are saying I need to add it in?

Comment: You should be able to just add it in anywhere in the function, so long as `e` is the event object.

Comment: I tried adding it into what I think is the event handler, but it just stops the carousel from working, and still highlights it

Comment: `e` may not be the variable name used for the event object.

Comment: Hi, I tried a few variable names, but still can't get it to work. I think I'll just work with making the select color white on the complete page as this jquery is over my head :(. Thanks